# how to set parameters into regexp_like in jpa

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, regexp-like

I have a query statement like this:

```
  @Query(value =
"select t.pt_note, t.tracking_no" +
  "  from T_EC_PURCHASE t" +
  " where regexp_like(t.pt_note," +
  "                   '^(.*[^[:digit:]]+)?(?1)([^[:digit:]]+.*)?$'," +
  "                   'n')", nativeQuery = true)
```

There is one parameter and i want to set it into the position ?1, but i got a error message:

> Using named parameters for method public abstract Purchase PurchaseRepository.getByTrackingNo(java.lang.String) 
>         but parameter 'trackingNo' not found in annotated query '
>         select t.pt_note, t.tracking_no  from T_EC_PURCHASE t where regexp_like(
>         t.pt_note,                   '^(.*[^[:digit:]]+)?(?1)([^[:digit:]]+.*)?$',                   'n')'!

The purchase is my entity, and here is PurchaseRepository:

```
trait PurchaseRepository extends JpaRepository[Purchase, String] with QueryDslPredicateExecutor[Purchase] {

  @Query(value =
    "select t.pt_note, t.tracking_no" +
      "  from T_EC_PURCHASE t" +
      " where regexp_like(t.pt_note," +
      "                   '^(.*[^[:digit:]]+)?(?1)([^[:digit:]]+.*)?$'," +
      "                   'n')", nativeQuery = true)
  def getByTrackingNo(trackingNo: String): Purchase
}
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Check out this [jpa native Query regexp like with querydsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984210/jpa-native-query-regexp-like-with-querydsl), maybe it helps you.