# jpa native Query regexp like with querydsl

Tags: jpa, querydsl, nativequery, regexp-like

I have i query statement like this:

```
select t.*
  from T_ex_table t
 where regexp_like(t.note,
                   '^(.*[^[:digit:]]+)?([condition])([^[:digit:]]+.*)?$',
                   'n')
```

And if I use it in jpa with querydsl(com.querydsl) like(this is scala, and it doesn't important):

```
 @Query(value =
    "select t.*" +
      "  from T_PURCHASE t" +
      " where regexp_like(t.note," +
      "                   '^(.*[^[:digit:]]+)?([?1])([^[:digit:]]+.*)?$'," +
      "                   'n')", nativeQuery = true)
 def getByTrackingNo(trackingNo: String): Purchase
```

While i debug test, it always throw

> Using named parameters for method public abstract Purchase
>   PurchaseRepository.getByTrackingNo(java.lang.String)
>   but parameter 'trackingNo' not found in annotated query 'select
>   t.pt_note, t.tracking_no  from T_EC_PURCHASE t where
>   regexp_like(t.pt_note, '^(.*[^[:digit:]]+)?({?1})([^[:digit:]]+.*)?$',              'n')'!

Did i missed something, and how can i fix it.

Comment: Please provide a little bit more logs and full method annotated by `@Query`, i tried your query on my project and it works without error, also describe what data base do you use.

Comment: Ok, I update it.

Comment: please check documentation [Using named parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters).  Spring-data waits for a parameter in the query (in your case `trackingNo`), or make a method with no parameters

Comment: I have tried it, but It throw Parameter with that position [1] did not exist.

Comment: It seem like jpa treat it as an ordinary string. And I cann't use  a no parameters method, because users will get data through this parameter.

Comment: Maybe try to move full regexp to the param method? and build it before. for example : `@Query(value =
    "select t.* from T_PURCHASE t where regexp_like(t.note, ?1, 'n')", nativeQuery = true)`. Where `?1` - yours fully build regexp with required parameters.

Comment: Yes. It work. Thank you very much. And can i just return one or many column(like t.note[,...] instead of t.*)?

Comment: Of course just search [spring data and projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420600/spring-data-projection-and-error-no-aliases-found-in-result-tuple-make-sure-y) for example.. Do not forget +++ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try to move full regexp to the param method? and build it before. for example :
 `@Query(value = "select t.* from T_PURCHASE t where regexp_like(t.note, ?1, 'n')", nativeQuery = true)` 
Where `?1` - yours fully build regexp with required parameters.